# Class objects created and assigned to a dictionary were changed

Tags: python, dictionary, oop

Code:

```
import itertools

class pt:
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    pt.x = x
    pt.y = y

tuple_list = list(itertools.product([x+1 for x in range(9)],[x+1 for x in range(9)]))
dict1 = {}
for i in tuple_list:
  dict1[i] = pt(*i)

print(dict1[(3,3)].x)
print(dict1[(3,3)].y)
```

Expected Output:

```
3
3
```

Output:

```
9
9
```

Why did it output `9 9`?

I wonder why the `pt` objects created and assigned to the dictionary were changed.  Do I need to create another list to store the `pt` objects? Does a dictionary only store the reference to the object (memory location) rather than the object itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
pt.x
pt.y
```

to

```
self.x
self.y
```

Right now you are overriding the class variables `x` and `y` every time you construct a `pt`. You want instance variables instead.

Comment: OH I MISSED THAT...! HAHA Thanks